# How to convert Data to AVAsset?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, avasset, avplayeritem

Is there a way to convert Data to AVAsset/AVURLAsset or better AVPlayerItem?
I found an answer that converts Data to PHAsset and requires saving it first to the desk.
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5):

Since I haven't found a way to do it without a temporary file, based on Elsammak's example, here's a little helper class that takes care of deleting the temporary file (keep the `TemporaryMediaFile` around as long as you are using the `AVAsset`, the temporary file will be deleted when the object gets deallocated, or you can call `.deleteFile()` manually on it):

```swift
import Foundation
import AVKit

class TemporaryMediaFile {
    var url: URL?

    init(withData: Data) {
        let directory = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory
        let fileName = "\(NSUUID().uuidString).mov"
        let url = directory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        do {
            try withData.write(to: url)
            self.url = url
        } catch {
            print("Error creating temporary file: \(error)")
        }
    }

    public var avAsset: AVAsset? {
        if let url = self.url {
            return AVAsset(url: url)
        }

        return nil
    }

    public func deleteFile() {
        if let url = self.url {
            do {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: url)
                self.url = nil
            } catch {
                print("Error deleting temporary file: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }

    deinit {
        self.deleteFile()
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```swift
    let data = Data(bytes: ..., count: ...)

    let tempFile = TemporaryMediaFile(withData: data)
    if let asset = tempFile.avAsset {
        self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(asset: asset))
    }

    // ..keep "tempFile" around while it's playing..

    tempFile.deleteFile()
```

Answer (score 3):

I managed to do it, here you are for anyone who is interested.

```
extension Data {
    func getAVAsset() -> AVAsset {
        let directory = NSTemporaryDirectory()
        let fileName = "\(NSUUID().uuidString).mov"
        let fullURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPathComponents: [directory, fileName])
        try! self.write(to: fullURL!)
        let asset = AVAsset(url: fullURL!)
        return asset
    }
}
```

Comment: The author asks if he can initialise AVAsset from Data without creating temporary file.

Answer (score -3):

You can do the following:
1. Use AVAssetExportSession to export your AVAsset object to a file path URL.
2. Convert it to NSData using its dataWithContentsOfURL method.

```
NSURL *fileURL = nil;
__block NSData *assetData = nil;
// asset is you AVAsset object
AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];

exportSession.outputURL = fileURL;
// e.g .mov type 
exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie; 

[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    assetData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];
    NSLog(@"AVAsset saved to NSData.");
}];
```

Don't forget to clean up the output file after doing whatever you need to do with it ;)

Comment: The author asks if he can initialise AVAsset from Data, not vice versa